# Automatically filled field in model

Tags: python, django

I have some model where there are date field and CharField with choices New or Done, and I want to show some message for this model objects in my API views if  2 conditions are met, date is past and status is NEW, but I really don't know how I should resolve this.

I was thinking that maybe there is option to make some field in model that have choices and set suitable choice if conditions are fulfilled but I didn't find any information if something like this is possible so maybe someone have idea how resolve this?

Comment: Can you add your view/serializer/model code (only relevant parts) to the question and add an example of expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need override the method `save` of your model. An overrided method must check the condition and show message
2. You may set the signal receiver on the post_save signal that does the same like (1).